# Optimize SQL with multiple BETWEENs in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...]
WHERE 
FirstInt BETWEEN 100 AND 200 AND
SecondInt BETWEEN 100 AND 200
```

Those variables have to be in the same range. Is there any way to write sth. like "*(a || b) between 100 and 200*"?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, presumably the type of the columns is `int`.

Comment: ' Is there any way ' - no there isn't.

Comment: "Optimize" does not usually mean to make it shorter or easier to write. It's commonly about improving performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for:

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...]
WHERE least(FirstInt , SecondInt, ... ) >= 100
AND greatest(FirstInt , SecondInt, ... ) <= 200
```

With this query you will find the smallest value of all of your columns(with function least) and compare it to the smallest value of your range. You will do the same with the largest value of all of your columns (with function greatest) and compare it to the largest value of your range.

Here is a small demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8ba1fefb0c0524d0626b1d0c4eae102)

With this query you can replace your multiple between statements or in other words you can use it when you want to copare multiple columns to the same range.

Comment: Hi @Martin, I see now I did not. Thanks for helping, my query in my answer was personalized to the demo I have added but I agree this is of more help to the OP. Cheers!

Comment: It's ok, I applied them twice, `;-)` Always a risk when both working in parallel. No worries

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand the question but i think you can use this.

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...]
WHERE 
FirstInt >= 100 AND FirstInt<=200 OR
SecondInt >= 100 AND SecondInt <= 200
```

Comment: I want to make it shorter. I have many variables that have to lie in between the same range.

Comment: @Mukeyii - But do you want _all_ of them to be between 100 and 200, or is it OK to have _any one_ of them in that range?